# Fortigate - cannot ping public IP in dual WAN ISP setup

Tags: networking, isp, fortigate

I have a fortigate 100c that is configured with 2 WAN ISP's

```
LAN1 -------------- ISP 1 (static pub  1.1.1.1)
      |-FORTIGATE-|
LAN2 ---------------ISP 2 (dynamic pub 10.1.1.1)
```

I have policy routes configured to both private LAN's and I have no problems regarding their uplink connection.

When I try to ping my static public IP (1.1.1.1) from external, I'm getting **RTO**.

But what baffles me, when I disconnect my WAN2, my ping to my static public IP address succeeds.

I need a setup where in I have 2 ISP without using failover and load balancing. Just a dedicated traffic for each of my LANs.

Comment: Well it should be rather easy to do that, close off your VLAN's and set the gateway for each VLAN to the accompanied ISP interface. But be warned, allowing the VLAN's to see each other might cause the exact problem you are facing.